# Which Hot Wheels vehicles are compatible with LEGO bricks?

Tags: compatibility, vehicle

I recently came across this Hot Wheels vehicle:

[image: Custom Small Block]

It includes a pair of LEGO-compatible elements along with studs that can be used to customize the vehicle. Are there other Hot Wheels vehicles that are compatible with LEGO?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am aware of 5 Hot Wheels castings that provide LEGO-compatible connections currently:

- [Custom Small Block](https://hotwheels.fandom.com/wiki/Custom_Small_Block)

[image: Custom Small Block]

- [Bricking Trails](https://hotwheels.fandom.com/wiki/Bricking_Trails)

[image: Bricking Trails]

- [Brick and Motor](https://hotwheels.fandom.com/wiki/Brick_and_Motor)

[image: Bricking Motor]

- [Brickin' Delivery](https://hotwheels.fandom.com/wiki/Brickin%27_Delivery)

[image: Brickin' Delivery]

- [Bricking Speed](https://hotwheels.fandom.com/wiki/Bricking_Speed)

[image: Bricking Speed]

These are all Mega collaborations created between 2021 and 2023. [Kevin Cao](https://hotwheels.fandom.com/wiki/Kevin_Cao) was designer for all of these.

There have been other collaborations in the past that were LEGO compatible, such as [Mega Bloks Hot Wheels 3-in-1](https://hotwheels.fandom.com/wiki/Mega_Bloks_Hot_Wheels_3-in-1), but these are more like building sets than traditional Hot Wheels cars. There is at least one element of interest in these sets, though. There is a [2x8 vehicle base](https://hotwheels.fandom.com/wiki/Mega_Bloks_2%C3%978) that is compatible with Hot Wheels track that can be used as the base for custom vehicles:

[image: 2x8 base]